# show data in columns wow/yoy comparison

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a table with week-on-week / year-on-year comparison in rolling manner.
From a simple table which has two columns "date" and "number of sales", I'd like to create the table like this.

```
week_no week_start  this_week   Last_week   last_year (same week)
1       31/12/2013  1504        1230            1601
2       06/01/2014  896         1504            788
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: looks like you can get this even with your simple table by using three joins

Comment: Thank you for the comment, sqlab.
I have no idea how it can be done with three joins but you sound like this question is too basic to ask here. Seems like I'm being in the wrong place. I'll seek for the help in other communitis or more books... 
I apoogise for being so beginner. 

B

Comment: no need to apologize Here you are at the right place. Just show your table and some data rows and then wait a little bit longer.